# How to use sqldatasource by showing only preferred data using session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, .net-framework-version

the usual way for me to do sqldatasource is this. Which just normally shows all forums in a table format.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:elibraryDBConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [forum_id], [forum_topic], [forum_description], [forum_status], [company_name], [replies_count], [publish_date], [publisher_name], [forum_img_link], [moderator_name] FROM [forum_accept_tbl]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

However, I want to show not all forum, but only one forum with session forum id that I've got. Below is the code that didn't work for me.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:elibraryDBConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [forum_id], [forum_topic], [forum_description], [forum_status], [company_name], [replies_count], [publish_date], [publisher_name], [forum_img_link], [moderator_name] FROM [forum_accept_tbl] WHERE [Forum_id] = Session["Forum_id"]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I tried to add WHERE but it didn't recognize the session. This is on my forum.aspx code btw. Should it be changed in forum.aspx.cs or not that necessary? I'm still new to asp.net and I think this is a simple mistake but I hope I can learn more.

**EDITED CURRENT PROGRESS.** After reading some useful documents suggested. Below is my current progress with the current error it shows.

```
                     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:elibraryDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [forum_id], [forum_topic], [forum_description], [replies_count], [forum_img_link], [company_name], [publisher_name], [publish_date], [moderator_name] FROM [forum_accept_tbl] WHERE ([forum_id] = @forum_id)"> <SelectParameters> <asp:SessionParameter Name="forum_id" SessionField="forum_id" Type="Int32" /> </SelectParameters></asp:SqlDataSource>
                     <div class="col">
                        <asp:GridView class="table table-striped table-bordered" ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                           <Columns>
```

I've checked the session and it works well (taking the right session forum id). however, after i run it and click for the link button, it shows this error below:

**Description**: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message**: CS1061: 'forum_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged' and no accessible extension method 'GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'forum_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**Source Error**: Line 44

```
Line 42:                      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:elibraryDBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [forum_id], [forum_topic], [forum_description], [replies_count], [forum_img_link], [company_name], [publisher_name], [publish_date], [moderator_name] FROM [forum_accept_tbl] WHERE ([forum_id] = @forum_id)"> <SelectParameters> <asp:SessionParameter Name="forum_id" SessionField="forum_id" Type="Int32" /> </SelectParameters></asp:SqlDataSource>
Line 43:                      <div class="col">
Line 44:                         <asp:GridView class="table table-striped table-bordered" ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView2_SelectedIndexChanged">
Line 45:                            <Columns>
Line 46:                               <asp:BoundField DataField="forum_id" HeaderText="forum_id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="forum_id" InsertVisible="False" >
```

So in my case, I took session forum id ( which is '14'), and to my expectation, it should have taken 14 from the database and shows it on the page. But instead, there is this error. can someone please explain? I've read some of the documents as well and I followed each step. I'm still new and trying to learn whatever I can.

Comment: white that sql command on code behind.

Comment: You mean do it at the aspx.cs file? which is the back end code? But what would be the syntax? cause its different when doing it in the front end right?

Comment: stackoverflow's syntax highlighter is actively telling you why this didn't work

Comment: @JavaStudent not really. This really old WebForms control executes SQL queries directly against the database specified by the  connection string. It was never popular as it has a *lot* of restrictions. It was only meant to be a replacement for VB6's data source controls in desktop applications. Which, btw, weren't that popular for anything more than very basic, single-table CRUD.

Comment: The connection is controlled by the control itself. Creating a connection in the code-behind has no effect. You won't find such code in the docs or any tutorials. Which makes me suspect you didn't look at the docs yet

Comment: start from [Querying Data with the SqlDataSource Control (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/querying-data-with-the-sqldatasource-control-cs)

Comment: If you're just getting into ASP.NET, don't bother with WebForms. It's not only very old and obsolete, it won't be migrated to .NET 5. Which, despite the name, is .NET **Core** 5. Start with [Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) instead

Comment: Passing parameters to SqlDataSource is explained in [Using Parameterized Queries with the SqlDataSource (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/using-parameterized-queries-with-the-sqldatasource-cs)

Comment: Thank you for all the documents that I've never actually know existed. I'm sorry for my inexperience. I'm actually very very new to this and I'm trying to learn whatever i can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to do this in code, you can write your sql like this:

```
WHERE [Forum_id] = @fid">
```

And then declare the parameters within the SqlDataSource (where you currently have `><`

```
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:SessionParameter Name="fid" SessionField="Forum_ID" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/z72eefad(v=vs.100)

Comment: Hello, this is very helpful! and I've looked and read the link that you've sent. but I updated my current progress. do you happen to know what's the cause?

Comment: It's a completely different question, I'm afraid. You should copy your current question text, edit your question back to its original presentation, accept this answer and then ask a new qustion. SO's mission is to be a Q&A of one problem -> one solution, with the aim that when someone else has the same problem they can get the same solution. It's not intended to start with someone asking "how do i start out in c#?" and after a succession of moved goalposts via repeatedly editing the question for every different problem, end up at "how do I write a unit test for my air traffic control system?"